# Can anybody help me identify this font I've searched everywhere

Tags: adobe-indesign, font-identification

I'm trying to find this font. I've looked all over the Internet with no luck. It would be much appreciated if anybody can help I havent a clue what font pack it come from I've used all the the font finders I can with no luck this font is used for jar label in the USA but I can only find simular fonts not the identical one

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  We have some [requirements for font ID questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/89608). It would be great if you could review these, and then edit your answer to provide the missing information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very close candidate: **VTCSuperMarketSaleDisplay**.

The characteristic lower "B" bow is there very close to your banana-word. 
In your sample image the designer may have distorted the letters to get a "narrow type".

[image]

> VTCSuperMarketSaleDisplay is a trademark of the VTC Vigilante Typeface Corporation. Copyright (c) VTC Vigilante Typeface Corporation, 1999

Comment: The font family is right, but the version is regular. Strokes and the outer shape are added in graphics software and the letter spacing is radically reduced.

Answer (score 1):

I differ - I think it's Komika Axis - not *close*; I think it actually ***IS*** Komika Axis, with no alterations or tweaks *at all*.

[image]

[What Font Is | Komika Axis](https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Komika-Axis.font?text=BNA)

Comment: Thank you kind sir this is indeed the exact font I was looking took me almost a year to find this much appreciated

Comment: If you feel this is a correct answer, please "accept" it - this improves the overall **GD.SE** statistics, allows easier search for future askers, and gives both you and I a boost in reputation - thanks!